# Getting blank response while making API call from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, api, t-sql

I have one working batch file which makes API call and download the response file. Now, I want to make API call from SQL server instead of using that batch file.

Bach file has following code:

```
curl -H "X-API-KEY:CDK5fvQodogejk1SFERTGSlbTJivgYNKuZHqyjEFl6zoyHdk8dBcw712Vwf"  https://app.guide.com/external/api/v1/bookings?from_date="2020-10-01"?to_date="2030-12-31" -o "\\LSRSQL01\Share\WorkingFolders\LUXC\AnyRoad\Road_JSON.txt"
```

T-SQL Code as below:

```
DECLARE @Object AS INT;
DECLARE @ResponseText AS VARCHAR(8000);


EXEC sys.sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
EXEC sys.sp_OAMethod @Object,
                     'open',
                     NULL,
                     'get',
                     'https://app.guide.com/external/api/v1/bookings?from_date=2020-10-01?to_date=2030-12-31',
                     'false';
EXEC sys.sp_OAMethod @Object,
                     'setRequestHeader',
                      NULL,
                     'X-API-KEY:CDK5fvQodogejk1SFERTGSlbTJivgYNKuZHqyjEFl6zoyHdk8dBcw712Vwf';
EXEC sys.sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send';
EXEC sys.sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT;

SELECT @ResponseText;

EXEC sys.sp_OADestroy @Object;
```

while running above code I'm getting blank response.

Comment: Making HTTP requests from SQL Server is a bad idea to begin with. Why do you want to do this? It's simply better to use the client program to do such connections.

Comment: @Alejandro, because I don't have any client program. Batch file is working fine but I don't want to store response in json file and again load that file to SQL Server. I am thinking of making API call from SQL Server and load the response directly to SQL Server.

Comment: @JayDesai Agreed with Alejandro, you're trying to use a screw driver to hammer in nails. But if you want to go that route, you should look into [CLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/common-language-runtime-integration-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) instead. It'll make it a lot easier to develop and manage.